# Make scrolling when content overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed bottom div using `top: 50%; bottom: 0px;`. I want a scroller to appear when text overflows the inner content div. If text doesn't overflow I want to hide the scroller.

[image]

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```
div.scroll {
        background-color: #00FFFF;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

<div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.myScrollableDiv {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

...on your scroller div. Without seeing what your code is, we can't help you with your CSS specifically.

Answer (score -1):

```
.className {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's wrong, that will show the scroller regardless

Comment: You've changed it to `overflow: auto`, now it's ok